# If there is a convenience method to get absolute path by (port, inode number, relative name)?

Tags: netstat

I want an answer in Linux C program, not shell (find / -inum xxx).

These are the details :
1. I have a program named 'my_netstat_plus', it likes 'netstat' to read the /proc/net/tcp(6).udp(6) and load some information(addr,port,inode...)

2. Now I wanna find the absolute pathname.

   - by port:  I use getservbyport to get the relative path , but it's not abs path!
   - by inode number: I can't find what's the use of inum in C/C++
   - by pid: /proc/pid/exe, but how can I get the pid?

I have seen some other method to get abs_path : travers the /porc/pid/fd to match the port, and get struct inode, then recurse to root dir.
but it's too trouble and waste performance.

so, my question: 
If there is a convenience method to get absolute path by (port, inode number, relative name)? 
or
If there is a convenience method to get pid by (port, inode number, relative name)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly: retrieve the all process in /proc//
secondly: read every process fd links, such as /proc//fd/1 links to socket:[12345], this 12345 is equal to the ino in question